# NameError: global name 'NAME' is not defined

Tags: ros, gps, publisher, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, I'm trying to publish data of my GPS but it appears this error

NameError: global name 'hora' is not defined

Anybody help me please :)

My code is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
import serial
import pynmea2
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('ceres_pkg')
from std_msgs.msg import String
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point

serialStream = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0",9600,timeout=0.5)

 class GPS(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pub_ = rospy.Publisher("/dat_gps", Point, queue_size = 1)
        return
    def start(self):
        sentence = serialStream.readline()
        global hora,lat,lon
        if sentence.find('GGA') > 0:
            data = pynmea2.parse(sentence)
            hora = data.timestamp
            lat = data.latitude
            lon = data.longitude
        pos_msg = Point(hora, lat, lon)
        loop_rate = rospy.Rate(1)
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            self.pub_.publish(pos_msg);
            loop_rate.sleep()
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('GPS_py', log_level=rospy.INFO)
    rospy.loginfo("%s: starting GPS node", rospy.get_name())
    Gps = GPS()
    Gps.start()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245537/nameerror:-global-name-%27name%27-is-not-defined/) by [DannyMB](https://answers.ros.org/users/28114/dannymb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2016-10-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-10-12**:
could you post the actual error output with a bit of context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error should occur in the case that `sentence.find('GGA') > 0` evaluates to `False`. Then, although being declared, `hora` is not defined, i.e., didn't get assigned any value.

---

Originally posted by [Philipp Schillinger](https://answers.ros.org/users/24945/philipp-schillinger/) with karma: 321 on 2016-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DannyMB](https://answers.ros.org/users/28114/dannymb/) on 2016-10-13**:
Thanks! that was the solution.